# How can i build android kernel with modern environment

Tags: android, android-emulator, kernel, qemu

There is a few step which is i followed for compile Android Kernel with Repo and build/build.sh. But i couldnt succeed about get bzImage or zImage to emulate with emulator.

- repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b android-msm-wahoo-4.4-android10-qpr3
- repo sync
- build/build.sh

and at the end of the Building Android Kernel page from Android web site (https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels) there is a section with the name that "Building a Boot Image" but i also couldnt find any place for download GKI boot image in order to create gki-ramdisk.lz4 and than be able to follow the instruction.

- BUILD_BOOT_IMG=1 SKIP_VENDOR_BOOT=1 KERNEL_BINARY=bzImage GKI_RAMDISK_PREBUILT_BINARY=gki-ramdisk.lz4 BUILD_CONFIG=common/build.config.gki.x86_64 build/build.sh

Answer (score 0):

The earliest [GKI](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/generic-kernel-image) kernel is 5.4 based and available from Android 11 onwards: [`android11-5.4`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android11-5.4). So, you will likely have a hard time with a 4.4 based kernel.

Having said that, to find the `ramdisk-recovery.img` on [ci.android.com](https://ci.android.com) as per the documentation, go to the release specific branch, e.g. [`android11-gsi`](https://ci.android.com/builds/branches/aosp-android11-gsi/grid?) and you will find the file in the artifacts of the `aosp_arm64` target.